# A complex top form determine complex structure

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ is a $2n$-dimensional real manifold and $\Omega\in \Lambda^{n}(T^{*}M\otimes \mathbb{C})$ be a complex top form. How does one determine a complex structure on the tangent space $TM$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every complex $n$-form on $M$ defines an almost complex structure. If $\Omega$ is such a form, it has to satisfy two additional conditions:

1. $\Omega$ is ***decomposable***, meaning that in a neighborhood of each point it can be written in the form $\Omega = \zeta^1 \wedge\dots \wedge \zeta^n$ for complex-valued $1$-forms $\zeta^1,\dots,\zeta^n$; and
2. $\Omega\wedge \overline\Omega$ is nowhere zero.

Assuming these two conditions are satisfied, we can define complex subbundles $T'M,\ T''M \subseteq TM\otimes\mathbb C$ by 
\begin{align*}
T'M &= \lbrace v\in TM\otimes \mathbb C: v\ \lrcorner\  \overline\Omega  =0\rbrace,\\
T''M &= \overline{T'M} = \lbrace v\in TM\otimes \mathbb C: v\ \lrcorner\ \Omega  =0\rbrace.
\end{align*}
I'll show below that that $TM\otimes \mathbb C = T'M \oplus T''M$, so we can 
define the almost complex structure $J\colon TM\otimes C\to TM\otimes C$ by 
$$J(v \oplus w) = iv - i\overline w$$ 
for $v\in T'M$, $w\in T''M$. It is immediate from this definition that $J$
takes real vectors to real vectors and $J^2 = - \operatorname{Id}$, so it is an almost complex structure.

To see that this makes sense, we need to check that 
${TM \otimes \mathbb C = T'M\oplus T''M}$. 
Let $p\in M$ be arbitrary and choose complex $1$-forms $\zeta^1,\dots,\zeta^n$ such that $\Omega = \zeta^1\wedge\dots\wedge \zeta^n$ in a neighborhood of $p$. The fact that $\Omega \wedge \overline\Omega$ is nowhere zero guarantees that $(\zeta^1,\dots,\zeta^n,\overline {\zeta^1},\dots,\overline {\zeta^n})$ forms a local coframe for $T^*M\otimes \mathbb C$. Let $(Z_1,\dots,Z_n,\overline Z_1,\dots \overline Z_n)$ be the dual frame for $TM\otimes\mathbb C$. Then it is easy to check that $T'M = \operatorname{span}(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ and $T''M = \operatorname{span}(\overline Z_1,\dots \overline Z_n)$, from which the claim follows.

Conversely, if $M$ is endowed with an almost complex structure, we can just take $\Omega$ (locally, at least) to be any nonvanishing $(n,0)$-form.

Of course, this only defines an *almost* complex structure. If you like this approach, I invite you to check that the almost complex structure is integrable if and only if $\Omega$ satisfies the following condition:
$$
\mathscr L_V \Omega \text{ is a function times $\Omega$ whenever $V$ is a smooth section of $T''M$}.
$$
In particular, this is the case if $\Omega$ is closed.

Comment: Sorry,I can’t prove integrability condition. Can you help me?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is closed it is simple that the almost complex structure is integrable. But I can’t use the integrability condition $d=\partial+\bar{\partial}$ to prove that.

Comment: The $T”M$ is $(-i)$-eigenbundle for $J$?

Comment: @Fidelgh.: Hint: Use the fact that $\mathscr L_{[V,W]} = \mathscr L_V \mathscr L_W - \mathscr L_W \mathscr L_V$. See the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1697192/1421) for proofs.

Comment: @Fidelgh.: Yes, $T'M$ and $T''M$ are the $i$ and $(-i)$-eigenbundles, respectively.

Comment: I knew this formula, but it use for prove only the condition implies integrability ie, if $\mathcal{L}_{V}\Omega=0$ for every $W,V\in T”M$ then from $\mathcal{L}_{[V,W]}\Omega=0$ we conclude $T”M$ involutive respect lie bracket an the almost complex structure is integrable. But the for conversely ie, for suppose integrable almost complex structure, I try to use the fact $d=\partial +\bar{\partial}$ however I can’t prove lie derivative of antiholomorphic vector field is zero.

Comment: @Fidelgh.: No wonder you're having trouble. I stated the integrability condition incorrectly. I've fixed it now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: thank you very much for correction,what is “function times” mean?

Comment: @Fidelgh.: It just means $\mathscr L_V\Omega = f\Omega$ for some smooth complex-valued function $f$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t do,because I couldn’t find to how the operators $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ action to $\Omega$

Comment: Why this condition naturally for you? And What is your approach for lie derivative? Always image it like Derivative a tensor field along  a flow or algebraic concept?